# directory namespace, login and session management in spring framework

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am new in spring framework and little confused in managing the directory structure according to the role of user like admin (all jsp will be inside admin directory), how to make login according to the user role like admin will have access only to the admin directory and the session of the user it's time out etc.

I have used this website as reference for login management using hibernate :-

```
http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-security-mysql-hibernate/
```

what i want to do is to protect the user from seeing the pages, which they do not have permission in spring and my project is managing the directory as their role like admin - admin directory, user - user directory and other user - other directory and home pages, when admin will login he will have access to the pages inside admin.

Using hibernate security framework how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **SPRING** security framework to achive that.

just add whatever filter you want to add in spring-security.xml.
For example: add

```
<intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
<intercept-url pattern="/user/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
```

It will create check that accessing controller mapping starting with /admin* will require admin login.

Go through spring security docs then configure security with help of below link:

[Steps for configuring spring security](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-example/)